# ES2016 typed objects - can they be used to statically constrain the shape of objects?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2016

Can the typed objects proposed for ES2016 be used for constraining the API of arguments?

For example:

```
function foo(options){
  // I want to guarantee that `options` has a single string property `bar`.
  // Can typed objects help me with this?
}
```

ECMA documentation:

- http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:typed_objects
- https://github.com/dslomov/typed-objects-es7

This is an edit of an earlier question.

Comment: Perhaps [*ecma.org*](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:typed_objects) can shed some light. The official name is "ECMAScript 2016".

Comment: A. I don't see how. B. even if the answer is *yes*, what can that be used for **today**? would you build a code base around that today, considering it might change tomorrow (might as in *really possible*)? C. TypeScript